# clearInterval() not working javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. This is what I tried to clear the interval, but it didn't work. Kindly help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var intervalId;
    $(window).focus(function(){
        var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('working');
        }, 5000);
    });

    $(window).blur(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
});
```

Comment: @NahuelIanni The question is alright buddy. Perfectly valid. What's wrong in this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Look at the changes made to it. It was just a piece of code. Even if the code was right, a "not working" without a clear statement of why it is not working or what the expected/current behavior is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not redeclare `intervalId`, then it becomes a local scope to the `focus` function:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('working');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Consider this part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var intervalId;
    $(window).focus(function() {
        // intervalId is not the same as the `window.intervalId`
        // The scope changes.
        var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
//------^^^---------- Remove this var.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @AhsanKhan I have updated your question by adding some text to it. Hope it is good for you, and please follow the same for subsequent questions. `:)`

Comment: @AhsanKhan Just add the `intervalId =` in the front.

Comment: @AhsanKhan Can you create a fiddle and explain it as a new question? Would be better for everyone?

Comment: @parveen kumar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548020/how-to-stop-function-on-blur