# How to stop function on blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

`myfucntion` = send request after 5 sec

```
document.ready(myfucntion)
$(window).focus(myfucntion)
$(window).blur(stop(myfucntion))
```

is this possible to stop a function on blur called previously in document.ready

Comment: are you using a `var timer = setTimeout(function, 5000)`? if so, you can just do `clearTimeout(timer)` on the blur function.

Comment: What's the contents of `myFunction()`

Comment: i tried that but didnt work any how thanks @rory McCrossan

Comment: @AhsanKhan Check my answer, maybe you have implemented in a wrong way?

Comment: @AhsanKhan You have a small mistake in your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a global timer:

```
var intervalId;
```

And it would be better to have two functions:

```
startfunction() {
  intervalId = setTimeout(function () {
    // send request after 5 seconds
  }, 5000);
}
stopfunction() {
  clearTimeout(intervalId);
}
```

And use them like this:

```
$(document).ready(startfunction);
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).focus(startfunction);
  $(window).blur(stopfunction);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to make what you want work

```
var timer; // make it global so it can be accessed inside functions

var myFunction = function () {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    //do something after 5 seconds
  }, 5000);
}

var stopMyFunction = function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

$(document).ready(myFunction)
$(window).focus(myFunction)
$(window).blur(stopMyFunction))
```